# Merging HTML pages in the build of React Project and then deploying to S3 Static Hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I am deploying this to S3 bucket and it is not working as expected.
I have used different policy settings of S3
I also have tried writing some rewrite rules but nothing is working.
If I try to go to the react app routes it just returns the index file without styles.

Hey,I am working on a project where I need to merge the build of React Project with the landing pages of generic HTML wesbite.
Steps I have followed are given below:

1. Generate new build of the react project.
2. Rename the build index.html to admin.html
   3- Update the entry point from manifest.json
   4- Copy files of my static website and pasting to the build folder ( now I have new index.html which is landing page)
   5- Wrote JSON config for firebase and deployed to server and it is working fine.
   I have tried Firebase hosting and it worked fine with some tweaks using some rewrite modes given below:

```
``"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/index",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/free",
        "destination": "/free.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/privacy",
        "destination": "/privacy.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/terms",
        "destination": "/terms.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/admin.html"
      }
    ],`
`
```

I have also tried this redirect rules of static hosting of S3

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "index"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "index.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "free"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "free.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "privacy"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "privacy.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "terms"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "terms.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": ""
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "admin.html"
        }
    }
]
```

but didn't work.
I am expecting same behaviour from s3 static hosting as well as if we need some changings we can simply edit from s3 browser but we can not achieve this on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered me then after some time I have found the solution.
For merging the builds you can copy the pages and their assets to public folder and generate the build and this buiild will contains all the assets of both react and simple html files.
Now

For landing page rename that page form `landing.html` to `index.html`
rename react app from index.html to admin.html or whatever you want to
Update the `manifest.json` file and change `index.html` to `admin.html`.

S3 Setup
For S3 setup static hosting
for index page set that to `index.html`
for error page set that to `admin.html`

(Note: If you have any redirect rules please remove those rules and keep it empty)

Now connect that bucket to your domain and you are good to go.